# Everything scatter on my website

Tags: html, css

Im building a small website, so the problem is the layout.

I use CSS for a layout on a full screen browser. Usually play with padding and margins to get my desired layout.

Then after I'm done and satisfied I'd try to reduce the size of the browser.  Then everything will scatter, align on top of one another.  How do I fix this problem?  I tried learning bootstrap but I don't really understand it yet..

Comment: Maybe you set the margins and paddings to a fixed value?

Comment: What you mean to a fixed value?   And how am I suppose to do it?

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more in depth - even add some of your code - but it sounds like you need to look into [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to target different device sizes

Comment: you can try to achieve it by using percentages values for margin but it would be faster to just use bootstrap, it's not really hard to understand how it works:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Let me go back to my bootstrap and look at it.

Comment: Can we see your code please?

Answer (score 0):

Use percentage when setting the width and height or when using paddings and margins. when using percentage (%), this will fit on every screen

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're having a problem with containers (divs). You should try grouping all the elements as concisely as possible so that you can have more relative control and play around with the "display: " function. Hoping it isn't overly complex, @James is on the money with the media queries, adding grids and programming their parameters based on screen size will allow you to be a lot more precise.

Comment: Thanks guys..  I'm on it.. I'll give feedback later

Answer (score 0):

I think I now get it.  I have to apply grid system before CSS positioning so that my positioning can be applied within the row/column but not the entire page.  So every screen size from small to large I have to set new rules with media queries. Thanks guys..